# On the number of group homomorphisms from $S_n$ to $S_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was studying the number of group homomorphisms from $S_n$ to $S_m$ with $n\geq m\geq 7$ [in this article](http://math.ucsd.edu/~doprea/math200/midterm-sol.pdf). I have some difficulty in understanding.

First of all, why such condition is given $n\geq m\geq 7$? If so, what will happen if $1\leq m\leq n\leq 6$ ?

Next, it is said that "if the kernel is $\{1\}$ the homomorphism is injective." This part is clear cause it refers to the property of group homomorphism. But then it is written that 
$|S_n|\leq |S_m|\Rightarrow n!\leq m!\Rightarrow n\leq m\Rightarrow n=m$.

Why should one claim that $n\leq m\Rightarrow n=m? $

What I though was this: injective group homomorphism on finite groups makes it surjective, but not sure if I am right. Please let me know.

Next, $\phi$ is bijective ( clear to me) and hence automorphism and hence "inner automorphism" (why ?) since $n\neq 6$: (again, why so?) $$\phi(\sigma)=\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$$ for some $\tau \in S_m$.

It is not clear then how many group homomorphism are we getting in this case? is it 1?

Please clear my doubts. Thanks in adavnce

Comment: In $S_m$ we can look at the subgroup fixing $m$ and then we get the subgroup $S_{m-1}$.

Comment: I apologise I could not get you.

Comment: I think @soloveichik wants to say that there is an injective homomorphism maps $S_{m-1}$ to $S_m$. Thus, we cannot conclude that $n=m$ from $n\leq m$.

Comment: $n \ge m$ is given in the first sentence of the question. So you can conclude $n = m$ if you also have $n \le m$.

Comment: ohh thats absolutely true. Wonder how come i missed that information !! thank you so much. Can you help me what are the answers of the rest i asked, please ?

Comment: For the rest: a homomorphism between two groups **of the same order** is surjective iff it is injective and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups (and presumably earlier course work) for why the question assumes $m \ge 7$. Note you aren't being asked to count the homomorphisms, but just to describe them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood. Between, it was asked ''describe all group homomorphism.." doesn't it mean as a consequence we are counting all of them ? Moreover, since $n\neq 6$ why it is inner automorphism ?